# datagridview to crystal report in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, crystal-reports

my complete code button click event
where i save to sample.xml for scheme...i use this schema for crystal report and then bind data as u suggested

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("BLOCK NO ", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("DATE ", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SESSION ", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("USN ", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SUBJECT CODE ", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SEAT/BENCH ", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SUPERVISOR ", typeof(string));

    SqlDataAdapter adptdate = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from blocks_allocation order by date,session,block,bench", con);
    DataSet DSall = new DataSet();
    adptdate.Fill(DSall);

    for (int j = 0; j < DSall.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        DataRow DR = DSall.Tables[0].Rows[j];
        dt.Rows.Add(DR.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString(), DR.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString(), DR.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString(), DR.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString(), DR.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString(), DR.ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString(), DR.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString());

    }
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    ds.WriteXmlSchema("F:\\pramodblde\\Bin\\Sample.xml");


    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("blockreport.rpt"));//rpt file path

    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ReportDocument** to bind your data to Crystal Report.

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();

ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("../blockreport.rpt"));//rpt file path

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);//your datatable

rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
```

Comment: got following error "Error 3 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportSource' does not contain a definition for 'ReportSource' and no extension method 'ReportSource' accepting a first argument of type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\pramodblde\test.aspx.cs 77 30 F:\pramodblde\
"

Comment: @pramod niralakeri , add a reference to CrystalDecisions.Web.

Comment: use CrystalReportViewer control  instead of CrystalReportSource, brother.

Comment: sorry to bother but getting following error "Invalid Argument provided. Failed to open a rowset bla bla bla"

Comment: as explained in my main question... i am writing data to xml and then to crystal report... initially crystal report data fields are set using xml file

Comment: so it generating that error (dont know where wrong) and even after binding data to it

Comment: Could you show your code now by editing your question?

Comment: i dont have teamviewer right now.. can u give little time to install it?